# I get an error: use of unassigned local variable 'artist', don't know what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: c#

```
private void btn_AddSongArtistPlaylist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Artist artist;

        if (cmbBox_AddSongPlaylistArtist.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            if (cmbBox_Artist.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                artist = new Artist(txtBox_NameArtist.Text, dateTP_BirthdatArtist.Value.Date);
            }
            else 
            {
                foreach (Artist a in Artists)
                {
                    if (a.Name == cmbBox_Artist.SelectedText)
                    {
                        artist = a;
                    }
                }
            }
            Song song = new Song(txtBox_Name.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtBox_YearBirthday.Text), artist, txtBox_PathToFile.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *potentially* unassigned variable `artist`. See:

```
private void btn_AddSongArtistPlaylist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Artist artist;
        if (cmbBox_AddSongPlaylistArtist.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            if (cmbBox_Artist.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                artist = new Artist(txtBox_NameArtist.Text, dateTP_BirthdatArtist.Value.Date);
            }
            else 
            {
                foreach (Artist a in Artists)
                {
                    if (a.Name == cmbBox_Artist.SelectedText)
                    {
                        artist = a;
                    }
                }
            }
            Song song = new Song(txtBox_Name.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtBox_YearBirthday.Text), artist, txtBox_PathToFile.Text); // right here!
        }
    }
```

If the second `if` statement evaluates to `false`, and there are no objects in the `Artists` collection, you will hit that `new Song` line with an unassigned variable. Try initializing `artist` to `null`.

```
private void btn_AddSongArtistPlaylist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Artist artist = null;
        if (cmbBox_AddSongPlaylistArtist.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            if (cmbBox_Artist.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                artist = new Artist(txtBox_NameArtist.Text, dateTP_BirthdatArtist.Value.Date);
            }
            else 
            {
                foreach (Artist a in Artists)
                {
                    if (a.Name == cmbBox_Artist.SelectedText)
                    {
                        artist = a;
                    }
                }
            }
            Song song = new Song(txtBox_Name.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtBox_YearBirthday.Text), artist, txtBox_PathToFile.Text); // now you're fine
        }
    }
```

Comment: Np, don't forget to accept and upvote if it solves your issue!